# Can I use /dev/null for the find command?

Tags: linux, unix, sh

I'm updating a shell script that uses the find command that follows symlinks:

```
find -L somedir ...
```

However, on some older platforms, the -L isn't supported and the command must use the older -follow syntax:

```
find somedir -follow ...
```

The "-follow" flag is deprecated on newer systems, so my strategy is to test if the command works with the newer -L flag, and if not fall back on the -follow flag.

The script currently runs on RedHawk 5.4.11, but the `find` incompatibility was discovered on an older Linux version.  I was directed to make this work on all Unix/Linux platforms.

So, while creating a dummy `find` command to test, I'm creating an empty temp directory in `/tmp` for the `find` command to return quickly.  I then found out that `mktemp -d` is not supported on the older systems, so I was going to create one the old-fashioned way.

It then dawned on me, "why not just try `/dev/null` as a temp dir instead of creating one?"  So I tried the command:

```
TEMPDIR=/dev/null
FIND_L_SUPPORTED=`find -L $TEMPDIR &> /dev/null; echo $?`
```

and it seems to work, but I'm not sure why (since `/dev/null` is not a directory), or if it's reliable on all platforms.

Two questions:

1. Is using `find` against `/dev/null` reliable on all platforms?
2. Any other solutions to my original `find` problem, where some platforms need `-L` but others need `-follow`?

Comment: The arguments to find aren't directories, they're paths.

Comment: Why do you think`-L` is deprecated?

Comment: `"on some older platforms, the -L isn't supported"` and `"The "-follow" flag is deprecated on newer systems"` makes sense to me ;-) Good luck to all.

Comment: To the O.P. : "reliable on all platforms" ? That's a tall order. Rather than hope advice you receive here will apply to the oldest,crustest machine in your (or your customers) environments, perhaps construct a positive assertion test (confirming `-L` or `-follow` are supported) else have your script fail (in what you hope is the super-rare case that an Unix doesn't support either).  If the fail message is clear about the problem and where it is being triggered, future maintainers will revere your name! Also rather than `mktemp`, why not just `mkdir -p path`?  Good luck.

Comment: Finally, `find -L /dev/nullX` produces an error message and sets `$?` to 1. Does that help? Good luck!

Comment: @shelter - What's the 'X' for in the /dev/null, or is that a typo?

Comment: the X in deliberate, to (hopefully) force an error on a non-existent path. Just an idea. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to support unknown platforms is not productive. Just because you get one non-standard aspect right (e.g., replacing `-L` with `-follow`) doesn't mean there aren't other non-standard behaviors you don't know about that could cause your script to break.

Instead, write your script to support the standard by default, but provide a flag that users can explicitly set to support *known* older platforms. For example,

```
if [ "$NON_STANDARD_FIND" = "no-L" ]; then
    find somedir -follow ...
else
    find -L somedir ...
fi
```

Then run the script as

```
my_script ...
```

or

```
NON_STANDRD_FIND=no-L my_script ...
```

as necessary.

In the end, document the platforms you *know* you can support and how to run your script correctly on those platforms. Users of other platforms should only run your script at their peril.